# I want solution for the following problem

Tags: tables

this is the code.i want to the simulation result analysis section first then the subsection parameter but the code does not show this.how can i solve this???????

```
\begin{figure*}[ht]
 \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{Capture.PNG}
  \caption{A system model for MIMO-OFDM Beamforming.}
  \label{fig:1}
\end{figure*}    

\section{Simulation Result Analysis}

\subsection{Parameter}
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\caption{MIMO-OFDM parameters for Beamforming in 5G}
\begin{tabular}{|c|c|} \hline    
Parameter Name & Value\\ \hline
Sampling Time (T) & 1\\ \hline
No of FFT (Nfft) & 128\\ \hline
Rolling Factor (beta) & .5 , .2\\ \hline
No of transmit antenna & 64,16 \\ \hline
No of receive antenna & 16,8\\ \hline
Antenna separation (deg) & 8,5\\ \hline
No of cluster (cl) & 1,3,6\\ \hline
\end{tabular}    
\end{table}
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of what you're getting at a moment, along with some clarifications as to the intended layout?

Comment: You surely guess that every question asked is about some problem, so your title "*I want solution for the following problem*" isn't really helpful finding your specific problem. Please try to improve the title.  Also note that multiple question marks do **not** reduce the time to get an answer.  Finally complete, but short examples are preferred.